# `find` command returns no results when adding -exec

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

When I run `find` with these arguments, it returns thousands of files:

```
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ sudo find . -not -user steven -or -not -group users | wc
   3508   17479  245851
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $
```

When I add an `-exec` argument, it behaves as if `find` returned no results and the return code indicates success:

```
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ sudo find . -not -user steven -or -not -group users -exec echo {} \;
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ echo $?
0
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $
```

(My goal is to use `-exec chown -v steven:users {} \;` on the results (hence `sudo`), but I'm using `-exec echo {} \;` above to illustrate the problem more cleanly and rule out `chown` as a contributing factor.)

I'm using gnu find under stock bash on Ubuntu Xenial:

```
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
steven@nook:/mnt/station/media $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because adjacent operations bind with an implied `-and` tighter that the explicit `-or`, and because, from the `find(1)` man page, "If the expression contains no actions other than -prune, -print is performed on all files for which the expression is true."

That means that `find` looks at the expression in your first example and sees

```
(-not -user steven) -or (-not -group users)
```

and performs `-print` on the result, as you expected.

`Find` sees your second example, however, as

```
(-not -user steven) -or ((-not -group users) -and -exec echo {})
```

That should echo all files belonging to user steven and not belonging to group users.

The solution is to add escaped parentheses around your expression before the `-exec`:

```
sudo find . \( -not -user steven -or -not -group users \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Great explanation of how it parsed the implicit grouping without grouping operators.

Comment: I think your answer would benefit if you *explicitly* mentioned the following crucial behavior of `expr1 -or expr2`: "`expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is true". It took me some time to understand why you wrote "belonging to user steven". It's not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two corrections to your command line.

First, the braces of the exec command need to be escaped or quoted to               protect them from expansion by the shell.  This is explicitly mentioned in the **find** man page.
There is also an example in the man page to clarify this requirement.

```
   find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;

   Runs  `file'  on  every file in or below the current directory.  Notice
   that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from
   interpretation as shell script punctuation.  The semicolon is similarly
   protected by the use of a backslash, though single  quotes  could  have
   been used in that case also.
```

---

Secondly, the scope & precedence of the `-or` expression needs to be clarified with parentheses (which also have to be escaped).

With the corrections, the following should work:

```
sudo find . \( -not -user steven -or -not -group users \) -exec echo '{}' \;
```

---

FWIW I prefer to pipe the output of the find command, and use xargs rather that deal with the syntax of `-exec`.

```
find . -not -user steven -or -not -group users | xargs sudo echo
```